# <identifier> expected - Indentation?

Tags: java

```
public class CoinFlip {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Get a random number
            //Decide the outcome of the coin flip
            //Get a second random number
            //Decide the outcome of a second coin flip
            //Print out which flip had a higher score
            //Print out the maximum of the two flips
            double myNumber;

            myNumber = Math.random();
        int score;
        if (myNumber < .4) {
                System.out.println("heads");
                score = 5;
        }
        else if (myNumber <.8) {
                System.out.println("tails");
                score = 2;
        }
        else if (myNumber <.85) {
                System.out.println("derr");
                score = 20;
        }
        else {
                System.out.println("go 2 sleep");
                score = -3;
        }

        System.out.println("arrgh the score for der flip wus: " + score);

        }
        public static int max(int a, int b);
            int a = score;
            int b = secondScore;
                int maxScore = Math.max(score, secondScore);
                    System.out.println(score, secondScore);
        {

        }
```

---

I get an  expected error down by int a and int b. Is it the indentation? I'm not sure what to do. I tried moving around the indentation and the brackets with no avail. I'm new at this and I'm stumped. I feel like it's a really simple problem.

Comment: In your `max` method, where do you define the variables `score` and `secondScore`?

Comment: You cannot name local variables with names of parameters. Voting to close as a trivial syntax issue.

Comment: Int a and int b part. I'm not sure if that's correct though.

Comment: You are trying to (re)define the variables `a` and `b` and assign them values of `score` and `secondScore`.  But where do you define `score` and `secondScore`?

Comment: I don't. Where was I supposed to define them?

Comment: @subash Your edit is totally invalid. Other than tabbing/spacing/etc for readability, DO NOT edit the code. You moved brackets and deleted invalid syntax. Rolled back.

Comment: @Adam It seems you need to learn more about types of variables and how Java handles their scope.  You might want to look at some online tutorials, such as [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html) or [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Indentation matters only for readability.  You have three issues that I can see:

1. You have no closing '}' on the entire class
2. Your max() method is a definition and should not have a ';' after it
3. Move the opening '{' in your max method above the logic of the method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1 yes, 2 doesnt exist, 3 wouldn't cause any problems

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CoinFlip {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get a random number
        // Decide the outcome of the coin flip
        // Get a second random number
        // Decide the outcome of a second coin flip
        // Print out which flip had a higher score
        // Print out the maximum of the two flips
        double myNumber;

        myNumber = Math.random();
        int score;
        if (myNumber < .4) {
            System.out.println("heads");
            score = 5;
        } else if (myNumber < .8) {
            System.out.println("tails");
            score = 2;
        } else if (myNumber < .85) {
            System.out.println("derr");
            score = 20;
        } else {
            System.out.println("go 2 sleep");
            score = -3;
        }

        System.out.println("arrgh the score for der flip wus: " + score);

    }

    public static int max(int score, int secondScore) {
        int a = score;
        int b = secondScore;
        int maxScore = Math.max(a, b);
        System.out.println("Score 1 = " + score + " Score 1 = " + secondScore);
        return maxScore;

    }
```

For your Problems see the syntax for

1. System.out.println
2. How to code a method and return a value
3. Declaring methods inside classes
4. All the best

Comment: You should add some sort of qualification/explanation for this code.